# DAT GUI - resizing input fields

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I am using Dat Gui to add a menu system into my application.

I have this in my html code:

```
<script src="js/dat.gui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js/dat-gui-style.css">
```

and in the dat-gui-style.css file I have this:

```
.dg .c input[type=text] { width: 350px; }
```

This allows me to set a custom width for the input fields in the menu system.  Which is almost exactly what I want to achieve.  However, it only works globally.  I wish to be able to control the width property for my input fields dynamically from within my js code.

I tried this:

```
guiTest = new dat.GUI({ autoPlace: false });

for (i = 0; i < theMenu.paramNames.length; i++)
{
    guiTest.add(theMenu, theMenu.paramNames[i]);
    guiTest.__controllers[0].domElement.style.width = '350px';
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone got any idea how to do this?

Comment: Maybe there is some other way to do this, but I just can't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `domElement` is actually an instance of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), then your syntax should be

```
guiTest.__controllers[0].domElement.style = 'width:350px';
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was just what I needed!