# DAT.GUI : modify width of text field in order to put a long text

Tags: javascript, css, dat.gui

I would like to increase the width of a text field with DAT.GUI library JavaScript.

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583216/dat-gui-resizing-input-fields), if I do (with `0 index` corresponding to the index `gui.add` field like done below):

```
gui.add(params, 'StartingVector').name('Starting Vector : ');
gui.__controllers[0].domElement.style = "width:100%";
```

But I can't set a long text in this field. Here's a capture of the field without `gui.__controllers[0].domElement.style = "width:100%";` :

[image: Text field without domElement.style]

Now below, a capture with `gui.__controllers[0].domElement.style = "width:100%";` and with a long text set in this field :

```
gui.add(params, 'StartingVector').name('Starting Vector with testing a long text like this : ');
```

[image: Long text field]

As you can see, I can't get to put a long text in this modified field (via `domElement.style="width:100%";`).

How can I enlarge this text field in order to put a long text?

PS: the dat.gui.js that I used is available on the following link [dat.gui.js][4]

**UPDATE 1 :**

@

I tested your solution to join the cases into only one (for putting a long text with the same color, ideally white text on black background). Here's the result :

[image: Capture Menu]

As you can see, the bottom case on the right hides the long text "`A Single long line just for some fun`" and finally, only "`A single lin`" appears. I would like to remove this grey case on the right and I don't know how to do it.

Here what I tried into my JS script (I took solution you suggested : "`4` is the forth row of the menu in my script"):

```
gui.__ul.childNodes[4].classList += ' longtext';
gui.__ul.childNodes[4].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].classList += ' full_width';
```

with CSS :

```
.longtext {
           line-height: 13px !important;
           height: 40px !important;
          }
    
.full_width {
             width: 100% !important;
            }
```

**UPDATE 2**

My script is available on [this link][6]. My issue is located between line 272 and 307, and especially '`StartingVector`' into `params` structure :

```
 272 var params = {
 273  GreatCircle : '',
 274  Rotationx : torusRotationInitX,
 275  Rotationz : torusRotationInitZ,
 276  StartingVector : '',
 277  ComponentVectorTheta : componentThetaInit,
 278  ComponentVectorPhi : componentPhiInit,
 279  CurrentVector : '',
 280  ComponentCurrentVectorTheta : componentCurrentThetaInit,
 281  ComponentCurrentVectorPhi : componentCurrentPhiInit,
 282  TotalDiffCovariantDerivative : '',
 283  ComponentCurrentTotalDiffTheta: componentCurrentTotalDiffThetaInit,
 284  ComponentCurrentTotalDiffPhi: componentCurrentTotalDiffPhiInit
 285 };
 286 
 287 // Set parameters for GUI
 288 gui.add(params, 'GreatCircle').name('Great Circle :');
 289 controllerRotationx = gui.add(params, 'Rotationx', 0.01, Math.PI-0.01, 0.001).name('Rotation x ');
 290 controllerRotationz = gui.add(params, 'Rotationz', 0.01, Math.PI-0.01, 0.001).name('Rotation z ');
 291 gui.add(params, 'StartingVector').name('Starting Vector with testing a long text like this : ');
 292 controllerComponentVectorTheta = gui.add(params, 'ComponentVectorTheta', minComponentTheta, maxComponentTheta, 0.01).name('Component &theta; ');
 293 controllerComponentVectorPhi = gui.add(params, 'ComponentVectorPhi', minComponentPhi, maxComponentPhi, 0.01).name('Component &phi; ');
 294 gui.add(params, 'CurrentVector').name('Current Vector :');
 295 controllerCurrentComponentVectorTheta = gui.add(params, 'ComponentCurrentVectorTheta', minCurrentComponentTheta,
 296                                         maxCurrentComponentTheta, 0.01).name('Component &theta; ').listen();
 297 controllerCurrentComponentVectorPhi = gui.add(params, 'ComponentCurrentVectorPhi', minCurrentComponentPhi,
 298                                       maxCurrentComponentPhi, 0.01).name('Component &phi; ').listen();
 299 gui.add(params, 'TotalDiffCovariantDerivative').name('Total Differential :');
 300 controllerCurrentTotalDiffComponentVectorTheta = gui.add(params, 'ComponentCurrentTotalDiffTheta', minCurrentTotalDiffTheta, maxCurrentTotalDiffTheta,
 301                                                  0.00001).name('Component &theta; ').listen();
 302 controllerCurrentTotalDiffComponentVectorPhi = gui.add(params, 'ComponentCurrentTotalDiffPhi', minCurrentTotalDiffPhi, maxCurrentTotalDiffPhi,
 303                                                0.00001).name('Component &phi; ').listen();
 304 
 305 // Adding from StackOverflow from Niket Pathak
 306 gui.__ul.childNodes[4].classList += ' longtext';
 307 gui.__ul.childNodes[4].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].classList += ' full_width';
```

As you told me, I used:

```
gui.add(params, 'StartingVector').name('Starting Vector with testing a long text like this : ');
```

but the phrase is stopped at "`with`" word, nothing appears after ( i.e "`testing a long text like this :`"

I have put your CSS:

```
.longtext {
                 line-height: 13px !important;
                 height: 40px !important;
                }

 .full_width {
          width: 100% !important;
              }
```

Here's a capture which illustrates the issue :

[image: long text doesn't appear entirely]

I don't want to put interactively the long text, I want to set it and fixed it (like others short text fields in the menu) : I don't want it to be modified by user.

**UPDATE 3**

With the solution suggested by Niket Pathak, right grey case is still present and hides the long text; here below a capture of the menu.

[image: Right grey case still present on the forth row of menu]

Comment: yes, this is because you have commented out the important property of full_width class. the code on that page is `.full_width {
          /*width: 100% !important;*/
          width: 100%;
       }` which can be seen by viewing source.

Comment: NIket Pathak: i have added important property and this doesn"t change anything, grey case on the forth row is still present and long text is not displayed (stopped at "with" word and hidden by right grey case)

Comment: all my apologies, your solution is working on Chrome ........ but not on Firefox (46 Version), do you know how to make it work on FF ? thanks

Comment: Niket Pathak : could you remove please your comment above (where threre is the link of my animation), i.e this one : " You should see the snippet that I have made. In your link, you don't need line 306. And line 307 should be gui.__ul.childNodes[3].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].classList += ' full_width'; for it to work since you are using the 3rd <li> element" . Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks, I will update my Firefox, It works currently on Chrome and Safari for Mac. Could you remove please the link of my animation in your above comment (i.e where you say "**the link works as expected for me (tested on Chrome for Mac** ...)"  ? Regards

Comment: the link works as expected for me (tested on Chrome for Mac, ubuntu (latest versions) and on Firefox for MAC, ubuntu(latest versions)). I can see the full text. Please clear your cache or try to check it again in an incognito window

Comment: a last question for learning purpose, what does "gui.__ul.childNodes[4].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].classList += ' full_width'; " exactly perform on the current forth <li> tag ? I mean, what's the link between full_width class (with CSS) and classList keyword ? thanks

Comment: [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) contains the class names applied. So we add the class `full_width` to the desired `<li>` item

Comment: and what does the incrementation  "+=" acheive ? What do you increment ? because of full_width is equal to 100%, what's the goal to increment in this case ? regards

Comment: check out [JS operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp). That is not an incrementation operator but is concatenation operator. So it concatenates two strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a simple combination of css & JS.
To go about this, we will

1. Create a class, say `.longtext` where we will define the styling that we need.
2. Select the correct `<li>` element and add our above css class to its [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to over-ride the li's existing styling like this:

   ```
   // var gui = new dat.gui.GUI();
   // ...
   // here childNodes[4] is the 4th <li> element that has long text.
   gui.__ul.childNodes[4].classList += ' longtext';
   // here childNodes[6] is the 6th <li> element having firstchild <div> whose firstchild is a <span> to which we add the class 'full_width'. 
   gui.__ul.childNodes[6].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].classList += ' full_width';
   ```

Checkout the following snippet in action:

```js
       var obj = {
           message: 'Hello World',
           displayOutline: false,
           maxSize: 6.0,
           StartingVector: 'Dummy Text',
           SingleLine: '',
           explode: function () {
              alert('Bang!');
           },
       };

      var gui = new dat.gui.GUI();
      gui.remember(obj);
      gui.add(obj, 'message');
      gui.add(obj, 'displayOutline');
      gui.add(obj, 'explode');
      gui.add(obj, 'StartingVector').name('Starting Vector with testing long text like this : ');
      gui.add(obj, 'maxSize').min(-10).max(10).step(0.25);
       gui.add(obj, 'SingleLine').name('A Single long line just for some fun');
      // add class to the correct 'li' element
      gui.__ul.childNodes[4].classList += ' longtext';
      // Navigate through the DOM & add class to the 'span' element
      gui.__ul.childNodes[6].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].classList += ' full_width';
```

```css
    .longtext {
        line-height: 13px !important;
        height: 40px !important;
    }
    .full_width {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.6.2/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to join the two horizontal cases into only one case. For example, in your solution above, we would have only "message Hello World" for first same row and "Starting Vector Dummy Text" for the forth same row (with same color) ? regards

Comment: @youpilat13 Joining two horizontal cases into 1 case? If you mean showing the label as a single long line, I have modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Niket Pathak: I just tested your last solution and I get difficulties for removing right grey case on the row and be able then to display all the long text. see please my **UPDATE 1** above

Comment: @youpilat13, please see the JS snippet. It is working exactly as you'd like. in the code `gui.__ul.childNodes[4].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].classList += ' full_width';`  should be changed to `gui.__ul.childNodes[6].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].classList += ' full_width';`  as in the code snippet.

Comment: ok, could you see please my **UPDATE 2** above, I give you more informations. Thanks

Comment: it does the job done but gives an error on Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge. The error is: "Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode". Do you know how to deal with this error?